# Django class problem

Tags: python, django

first excuse me for my english it isn't the best one.

I'm pretty new to django and python and i try to programm a user authentification.
I used the django documentation and everything works fine with these code below:

```
def anges(request):

        username = []
        password = []

        if request.method == "POST":
                username = request.POST['username']
                password = request.POST['password']
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                render_to_response ('registration/login.html', {'username': username, 'password': password})

                if user is not None:
                        if user.is_active:
                                login(request, user)
                                angestellte_list = Employee.objects.all().order_by('lastname')
                                return render_to_response(("emp/angestellte.html"), {'angestellte_list': angestellte_list})
                        else:
                                return HttpResponse('disabled account')
                else:
                        return HttpResponse('invalid login')
        else:
                return render_to_response ('registration/login.html', {'username':username, 'password':password})
```

But this is just a function and i want to use this object oriented for my other functions in my views.py, because of DRY.
This is just a first test but it doesn't works because the debugger says:"global name 'request' is not defined"
That's my code:

```
class einloggen:

        def __init__(self):
                self.Username = request.POST['username']

        def angestellte(self):
                return HttpResponse("hello")
```

How can I use the request variable in classes or is there anything more to consider?

Comment: Django already has a complete User Authentication application.  Why write your own?

Comment: ... or in other words, what does `django.contrib.auth` lack that you need?

Answer (score 2):

Quite obvious that you can't use the `request` variable in `__init__` in the `einloggen` class, because, quite frankly, you don't send the request variable in to the constructor.

I can't see you making a `einloggen` object anywhere in your view either, but you should probably to something like:

```
class einloggen:
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.Username = request.POST.get('username')
```

and then in your view (where you've got the request variable):

```
def anges(request):
    myobj = einloggen(request)
```

---

However, Django already has an authentication system. And you'd be much better off using that. You can use the beautiful decorators to make it really easy and nice to «protect» views.